# MySQL Select Where In Subquery Only Showing 1 data

Tags: mysql

I want to show all the data in the table b. But what I get is only 1 data, while the data I have is more than 1.

Here's table a:

```
id | id_category | status
---+-------------+-------
1  +  Null       +      0
2  +  Null       +      0
3  +  59,76,55   +      1
```

Here's table b:

```
 id |    name     | status
 ---+-------------+-------
  59+   data1     +      0
  76+   data2     +      0
  55+   data3     +      1
```

And here's the query:

```
select name
from table_b 
where id IN (
                select id_category 
                from table_a 
                where status = 1
            )
```

The data did i just get is only data1. Is there anything wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] b.id, b.name, b.status
FROM table_b b
JOIN table_a a ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.id_category)
```

Comment: Nice answer but `[DISTINCT]` should be `DISTINCT` only. Otherwise it will through syntax error.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra *but [DISTINCT] should be DISTINCT only* - I don't know does it needed at all - so I mark it as questionable/optional.